# error cannot resolve method getSystemService(java.lang.string) in cardadapater recyclerview

Tags: android

Using `getSystemService` in **cardadapter** of recyclerivew shows error cannot resolve method `getSystemService`.

```
textViewFile_url.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
        dm = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
         DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
        Uri.parse("http://laqshya.edutracker.in/uploaded_notes/Desert.jpg"));
        enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
        }});
```

Comment: you should try get system service from an context object. ex: dm = (DownloadManager)view.getContext().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

Comment: thanks a ton bro how to close this topic coz i got answer

Comment: so should i delete or leave as it is for further reference for others